# Forge .NET API RuntimeBinderException

Tags: .net, autodesk-forge

I'm using Forge .NET API 1.3.0

I'm trying to get hubs via API, just like it is described in the [example](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/HubsApi.md)

I know that...

- My authentication works
- Query results correct data

But for some reason the following line fails with RuntimeBinderException:

```
Hubs hubs = apiInstance.GetHubs(/*filterId, filterExtensionType*/);
```

The exception message says:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' in Unknown Module.
>   Additional information: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Autodesk.Forge.Model.DynamicJsonResponse' to 'Autodesk.Forge.Model.Hubs'

So obviously the method example shows is not valid anymore (?). How should the resulting data to be converted into Hubs type.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to get it working by using the raw data. Following an example:

```
var hubs = await hubsApi.GetHubsAsync();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> hubInfo in new DynamicDictionaryItems(hubs.data))
{
  new { Id = hubInfo.Value.id, Name = hubInfo.Value.attributes.name }
}
```

For a reference, following kind of data is inside the "hubs.data" array:

```
{
"type": "hubs",
"id": "b.aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-1111-222223333333",
"attributes": {
    "name": "The hub",
    "extension": {
        "type": "hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account",
        "version": "1.0",
        "schema": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/hubs:autodesk.bim360:Account-1.0"
        },
        "data": {}
    }
},
"links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-1111-222223333333"
    }
},
"relationships": {
    "projects": {
        "links": {
            "related": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/project/v1/hubs/b.aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-1111-222223333333/projects"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The [.NET tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io) shows how to list hubs, you can also download the [ready-to-use sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/tree/net), the `DataManagementController` code shows it in action, [see here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/blob/net/forgesample/Controllers/DataManagementController.cs#L74).

Comment: Thanks! I found an example, and got it working (my example below). Although this didn't answer the question of how to convert directly into `Hubs` type. In the tutorial the caller is doing the parsing manually. I believe that's what **ought to be avoided** by using `Hub` and `Hubs` types from the .NET Forge API.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.
I solved it using Json Deserializer.

```
        string token = "a token";
        var apiInstance = new HubsApi();
        apiInstance.Configuration.AccessToken = token;

        // Get Hub
        dynamic hubsJson = apiInstance.GetHubs();
        Hubs allHubs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hubs>(hubsJson.ToString());
```

Now the json object is converted to the Forge Api Hubs class.